# Java: Remove double from string and store in array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string that will be different each time but follow the form of 
-3.33,-46.53,37.39,26.55,97.11,68.46,-32.46,-5.89,-62.89,-7.9,
and i want to remove each number and store as an double in an array.
even pseudocode would be great i'm drawing a blank.
Cheers

Comment: Cheers folks, Just wondering would I be better off using an arraylist as I'm reading from a file and don't know how big each file will be

Comment: You should try asking that as a separate question with some more details, but if you have an unknown amount of lines like these, then that is what an Array list was designed for. If it is all on one line, read in memory at once, then a pre-allocated array makes some sense.

Comment: Thanks folks, Still having trouble but i'll ask in a seperate post to clarify things. Cheers again.

Answer (score 4):

```
 String[] doubles = myString.split(",");
```

then iterate over the doubles array and do Double.parseDouble();

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way, reads input from file and parses items as thy are read.

```
static java.util.ArrayList<Double> getData(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    java.util.ArrayList<Double> result = new java.util.ArrayList<Double>();
    java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(filename));

    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    while (sc.hasNext())
        result.add(Double.parseDouble(sc.next()));
    sc.close();

    return result;
}
```

If you want, you can just store them in a array like:

```
    Double data[] = null;
    getData("input.dat").toArray(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
String[] sa = yourString.split(",");
Double[] da = new Double[sa.length];
int idx = o;
for(String s : sa) {
   da[idx++] = Double.parseDouble(s); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string based on the ',' and store into a string array.

```
String[] arr= Str.split(",");
```

Then make a double array and put the each str values into that double array.

```
Double[] res= new Double[arr.length];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    res[i] = Double.parseDouble(arr[i]); 
}
```